# How to check TalkBack on/off status and get change notifications in Android mobile?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, accessibility, talkback

I'm working on an Android mobile application and need to know if TalkBack is active on startup and detect TalkBack off/on state changes while application is running.

Previously the code used JavaScript accessibility component and called  C++ and then Java. Now we only want Java code.

How can I implement this functionality?

Comment: Android uses TalkBack and iPhone uses Voiceover so I'm guessing you're asking how to detect if TalkBack is running?  Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116867/how-to-know-if-android-talkback-is-active

Comment: Yes, those answers discuss checking for TalkBack status but I'd like to be notified via a callback event if the status change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the Talkback active/inactive status notification using AccessibilityManager.addTouchExplorationStateChangeListener. This resolved the issue I had with Android mobile.

```
    try {
        am = (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);

        am.addTouchExplorationStateChangeListener(new AccessibilityManager.TouchExplorationStateChangeListener () {
            @Override
            public void onTouchExplorationStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
                onTalkbackStatusChanged(enabled);
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception ex) {
       ...
    }
```